# php Loop through all skus in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, php

I need to write to mysql database related products and upsells. This should be done by php. I can now set this for 1 product, but need to loop through all the products. My script:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

require_once "blablabla/app/Mage.php";//my path here
umask(0);
Mage::app();


$sku="876297-6";  //some Sku
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);

$param = array(
101=>array(
'position'=>3
),
102=>array(
'position'=>5
)
);
$_product->setRelatedLinkData($param);
$_product->save();

echo "Great!!";

 ?>
```

What I cannot do is the following:

1.Get all product IDs
  2.For each product ID set a related product as a random product from collection

Position does not matter at all.    + do this until there are 20 related products would be cool, but I can also run script 20 times, no pressure. Better to work with product IDs and not skus.

My script is just example. main purpose is to set 20 random related products to each product 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: so, what you basically need is to set for each product 2 (or more) related products, right? Always the same products. From your script I understand you need to set the products with ids 101 and 102 as related products to all the other products. Did I get it right?

Comment: my script is just example.. main purpose is to set 20 random related products to each product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looping through all products using the Magento ORM is not the best idea. It's really time consuming.
Try instead to get all the ids and then run a simple sql query that will insert a row in the database.

Here is how you can get all the ids:

```
$ids = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->getAllIds();
```

Once you know what product needs to be added as related for an other product do this:
Let's say that `$mainId` is the id of the main product and `$relatedId` is the id of the related product.

```
"INSERT into catalog_product_link SET 
    product_id = $mainId,
    linked_product_id = $relatedId,
    link_type_id = 1
"
```

1 is the link type id for related products.

Comment: How can i only get the product id's for the category page i'm currently on?

Answer (score 0):

Final script, made by AreDubya:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

require_once "/blablabla/app/Mage.php";//my path
umask(0);




Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);




$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

$writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');

$ids = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->getAllIds();
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $mainId = $id;
    $relatedId = $ids[array_rand($ids)];
    echo "$id - $relatedId<br/>";
    $query = "INSERT into catalog_product_link (product_id,linked_product_id,link_type_id) VALUES ($mainId, $relatedId ,1)";

    $writeConnection->query($query);
}




echo "done";



 ?>
```